# How to Pass Variable Value On Page_Load Of Same asp webform

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, webforms

I want to send variable value from C# behind Code to same webform page on  Page_load function

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       String ActiveClass = "active";
    }
```

To Same Webform

```
<asp:ListView ID="LVCateMenu" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <li class="<%# ActiveClass%>"><asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="#"><%#Eval("cate_name") %></asp:HyperLink></li>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Describle in more detail

Comment: i want to Send variable Value to Html control or asp Control on Page_Load Event

Comment: For that you can either declare ASP control which can be easily access on client side.

Comment: In php as far as i know. just declare variable on top and use in html section <?php? inside this tag. but in asp i need variable data in html control. i want to use data dynamically for assign value in html div tag in class... Example: String myVariable = "Active"; <div class='<%myVariable%>' > </div>     .. sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:ListView ID="LVCateMenu" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <li class="<%=Response.Write(ActiveClass);%>"><asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="#"><%#Eval("cate_name") %></asp:HyperLink></li>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare variable protected or public to use in front page

Comment: In php as far as i know. just declare variable on top and use in html section <?php? inside this tag. but in asp i need variable data in html control. i want to use data dynamically for assign value in html div tag in class... Example: String myVariable = "Active"; <div class='<%myVariable%>' > </div>     .. sorry for my english